# Appending variable into a string with quotes

Tags: jquery

I have a problem appending a variable to a string which is already concatenated.

```
var count = $("#salesdetaildata").children.length;
var data ="<td name='Data[appendhere]'></td>";
```

I need to append the count variable into the place where **"appendhere"** is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add data into the string by using `+` signs. At least that's what I'm assuming you're after:

```
var count = $("#salesdetaildata").children.length;
var data ="<td name='Data["+count+"]'></td>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `+` to append variable with string

```
var count = $("#salesdetaildata").children.length;
var data ="<td name='Data[" + count + "]'></td>";
```

If your requirement is to append without square brackets then use following

```
var count = $("#salesdetaildata").children.length;
var data ="<td name='Data" + count + "'></td>";
```